# Haskell: Sort Vector of custom Datatypes

Tags: haskell

How do I sort a Vector of custom data types using `sortBy` from `Data.Vector.Algorithms` ie:

```
data Person = Person 
  { name :: String
  , age  :: Int
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

p1,p2,p3 :: Person
p1 = Person "Alice"   30
p2 = Person "Bob"     20
p3 = Person "Charles" 10

personVec :: Vector Person
personVec = fromList [p2,p1,p3]
```

I would like to do something like:

```
sortedByName :: Vector Person
sortedByName = modify (sortBy (comparing name)) personVec

sirtedByAage :: Vector Person
sortedByAge  = modify (sortBy (comparing age)) personVec
```

but don't know what to put as the argument to `sortBy`

Comment: It looks like your type declarations are wrong for `personVec`, `sortedByName`, and `sortedByAge`. Please edit your question to include all the compiler errors.

Comment: Are you aware `personVec` is not a `Vector Person` but a `[Person]` (linked list)?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson thank you. I have edited it

Comment: You're missing parentheses - it should be `modify (sortBy (comparing age)) myVec`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Present the problem**

Please include an MCVE including imports, pragma, the code, and errors.   Ex:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
import Data.Vector
import Data.Ord
import Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro

data Person = Person.
  { name :: String
  , age  :: Int
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

p1,p2,p3 :: Person
p1 = Person "Alice"   30
p2 = Person "Bob"     20
p3 = Person "Charles" 10

personVec :: Vector Person
personVec = fromList [p2,p1,p3]

sortedByName :: Vector Person -> Vector Person
sortedByName = modify sortBy (comparing name) personVec

sortedByAge :: Vector Person -> Vector Person
sortedByAge  = modify sortBy (comparing age) personVec
```

When loaded via `ghci-8.4.3 $file`, produces errors including this last one of:

```
so.hs:23:31: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Vector a1’
                  with actual type ‘Person -> Person -> Ordering’
    • Probable cause: ‘comparing’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘modify’, namely ‘(comparing age)’
      In the expression: modify sortBy (comparing age) personVec
      In an equation for ‘sortedByAge’:
          sortedByAge = modify sortBy (comparing age) personVec
   |
23 | sortedByAge  = modify sortBy (comparing age) personVec
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

**Parens For Args**

The `modify` function takes 2 arguments but you are passing three due to lack of parenthesis:

```
sortedByAge = modify (sortBy (comparing age)) personVec
```

**Types: Is this a vector or a function?**

Your `sortedByAge` variable is named to imply it is a vector but the type you provide shows it is a function that computes a vector.  Let's change that type:

```
sortedByAge :: Vector Person
```

Same goes for `sortedByName`.

**Result**

```
*Main> sortedByName
[Person {name = "Alice", age = 30},Person {name = "Bob", age = 20},Person {name = "Charles", age = 10}]
*Main> sortedByAge
[Person {name = "Charles", age = 10},Person {name = "Bob", age = 20},Person {name = "Alice", age = 30}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped a lot and also has shown me how to present my questions better!